# After switching back to bash can't access root

Tags: linux, bash, debian, shell, zsh

I'm new to Linux and using Debian 7. I was using bash, but tried out zsh by using chsh. Initially probably entered a bad shell name but eventually switched to zsh successfully.

Now I switched back to bash but can't access root

When I hit su and the password it returns "Cannot execute zsh: No such file or diretory", while apparently I'm using bash.

Additionally, when I changed back to zsh it still said the same, "can't execute zsh ..."

Can someone help please?

Thanks!

violeaf

Comment: Have you tried creating a new shell? Close your terminal program and reopen it.  You could alternatively just type 'bash'.

Comment: If you mean using another shell other than bash or zsh then I haven't, but will give it a go and let you know. Thanks! By the way I'm using the GNOME terminal.

Comment: Did you `chsh` to `zsh` for both your non-root account as well as the root account and later uninstalled `zsh`? It sounds like your root account still uses `zsh` and that you only switched your non-root account back to `bash`.

Comment: You might have `chsh`'d your root shell to just `zsh` (without path) instead of `/bin/zsh` (but `chsh` should have warned you about that) in which case it cannot find the shell.

Comment: Adrian I think this may well be the case. How can I now chsh the root shell back? Tried Tommi's suggestion but didn't work. Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is why you want to always stay logged in in a second terminal while you muck with your login settings.

As for recovery after locking yourself out: Since you have physical access just boot from a live cd, then mount the system partition on your disk, and edit `/etc/passwd` manually. Or reboot, go to the grub prompt, and add `init=/bin/sh` to your kernel command line.

Comment: Thanks @vbraun, before everything I had to navigate to /bin before I was able to get root access under zch.
Then instead of using a live cd I sudo'd gedit the passwd and changed the shell value to /bin/bash wherever it appears, now it seems to work. Thanks again for all your help

Answer (score 0):

su -s /bin/sh -c chsh root

And this time make sure you provide full path.

Comment: Tommi I typed this in and my password, but got 'Cannot execute zsh'

Comment: simply doesn't work, this is stupid.

Comment: Care to elaborate why you think it's stupid? If he had /bin/zsh listed in /etc/shells (which I'm assuming is the case here), then the -s will work with su. I even made sure it works by first switching my root (who uses /bin/zsh by default) to use /bin/bash. Then I moved /bin/bash to /bin/bash.disabled. Failed to login as root as described here. Ran the exact above command I posted and    was able to change shell back to my default inspite of what root had for him in /etc/passwd.

Answer (score 0):

type $ sudo bash
it ask for password
enter password
then type

## cd /etc (press enter)

type # nano passwd
press enter
thn change ur passwd file (replace zsh wit sh)